Why is ReplaceAll unable to replace square root?
The following is my code.
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
A[x_, y_, z_] := \[Mu] I L /(4 Pi r) E^(-I \[Beta] r);
Curl[{0, 0, A[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]/. Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] -> r

Clearly, the square root is still there.

You have assigned r to be the Sqrt expression.  When you substitute back to r it immediately goes back to the Sqrt expression according to your first statement.  Clear[r] before your Curl statement and it works.

r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
A[x_, y_, z_] := \[Mu] I L/(4 Pi r) E^(-I \[Beta] r);
Curl[{0, 0, A[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}] /. 
 Power[Plus[Power[x, 2], Power[y, 2], Power[z, 2]], a_] :> 
  HoldForm[r]^(2 a)



ReleaseHold[%]

